# relating website payments standard and IPN?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Im using Website Payments Standard so users can pay for a rating to be shown on their profile. Im also using IPN to check if the payment went through. How do I relate the two? When I get an IPN request to my listener, how do I know which user and rating it relates to?

Answer (score 0):

If users are initiating payment through a buy it now or shopping cart button embedded in your site, you can set some sort of text box where the user enters their user name. this info will be sent with the Ipn. This is set up on the pay pal sure where you create the buttons.

Another method would be get their actual name from the ipn. Check the documentation for a list of variables that are sent with the ipn, there are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: A commonly used method is to pass in some unique identifier from your end in the 'custom' parameter (CUSTOM=xxxx in SetexpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment, or `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="xxxxxx">` for Website Payments Standard).

Comment: I used <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="xxxxxx"> and that worked. Thanks for the help